# Using Shared Preferences to store data and display it even if activity is changed or app closed

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, onresume

I have an application that tracks the medical stock level of medications such as inhalers. I have a picture of an inhaler and then a variable that holds the amount of doses left in it. This is the same for other inhalers and tablets. The user has the ability to click a "minus" button which will decrease the amount of doses/tablets by 1.

I am trying to save the numbers that the user has left the screen with, for example, if they've decreased the doses from 200 to 150, i want 150 to show when they go back into that activity again.

The approach i have taken is to use Shared Preferences but on testing it has not worked and the medication levels have just displayed what they are set to in the OnCreate() method.

Here is my code:

```
public class ManageMedication extends AppCompatActivity {


Button minusblue;
Button minus2;
Button minus3;
Button minus4;

int inhalerlevelblue = 200;
int inhalerlevelbrown = 200;
int inhalerlevelred = 120;
int tabletlevel1 = 50;
int tabletlevel2 = 50;
int levelshowninhaler2;

int newlevel1;
int newlevel2;
int newlevel3;
int newlevel4;
String shownewlevel1;
String shownewlevel2;
String shownewlevel3;
String shownewlevel4;


TextView displaylevel;
TextView displaylevel2;
TextView displaylevel3;
TextView displaylevel4;

String showInhalerLevel;
String showInhalerLevel2;
String showtabletLevel2;
String showtabletLevel1;
String levelbrown;
String levelred;

Spinner spinnerInhalers;
ImageView imageView2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.managemedication);

    minusblue = findViewById(R.id.buttonminus);
    minus2 = findViewById(R.id.buttonminus2);
    minus3 = findViewById(R.id.buttonminus3);
    minus4 = findViewById(R.id.buttonminus4);


    showInhalerLevel = String.valueOf(inhalerlevelblue);
    showInhalerLevel2 = String.valueOf(levelshowninhaler2);
    showtabletLevel1 = String.valueOf(tabletlevel1);
    showtabletLevel2 = String.valueOf(tabletlevel2);
    levelbrown = String.valueOf(inhalerlevelbrown);
    levelred = String.valueOf(inhalerlevelred);

    spinnerInhalers = findViewById(R.id.spinnerInhalers);


    displaylevel = findViewById(R.id.textViewStockBlue);
    displaylevel2 = findViewById(R.id.textViewStock2);
    displaylevel3 = findViewById(R.id.textViewStock3);
    displaylevel4 = findViewById(R.id.textViewStock4);

    imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    displaylevel.setText(showInhalerLevel);
    displaylevel3.setText(showtabletLevel1);
    displaylevel4.setText(showtabletLevel2);

    minusblue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            inhalerlevelblue = inhalerlevelblue - 1;
            newlevel1 = inhalerlevelblue - 1;
            shownewlevel1 = String.valueOf(newlevel1);
            displaylevel.setText(shownewlevel1);
        }
    });

    minus2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            levelshowninhaler2 = levelshowninhaler2 - 1;
            newlevel2 = levelshowninhaler2 - 1;
            shownewlevel2 = String.valueOf(newlevel2);
            displaylevel2.setText(shownewlevel2);
        }
    });

    minus3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tabletlevel1 = tabletlevel1 - 1;
            newlevel3 = tabletlevel1 - 1;
            shownewlevel3 = String.valueOf(newlevel3);
            displaylevel3.setText(shownewlevel3);
        }
    });

    minus4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tabletlevel2 = tabletlevel2 - 1;
            newlevel4 = tabletlevel2 - 1;
            shownewlevel4 = String.valueOf(newlevel4);
            displaylevel4.setText(shownewlevel4);
        }
    });

    final ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(ManageMedication.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.inhalers));
    myAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerInhalers.setAdapter(myAdapter2);

    spinnerInhalers.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position2, long l) {


            switch (position2) {
                case 0:
                    imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.browninhaler);
                    displaylevel2.setText(levelbrown);
                    levelshowninhaler2 = inhalerlevelbrown;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.redinhaler);
                    displaylevel2.setText(levelred);
                    levelshowninhaler2 = inhalerlevelred;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.inhalers);

            spinnerInhalers.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(list[0]));
        }

    });

}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putInt("newlevel1", newlevel1);
    editor.putInt("newlevel2", newlevel2);
    editor.putInt("newlevel3", newlevel3);
    editor.putInt("newlevel4", newlevel4);
    editor.putString("shownewlevel1", shownewlevel1);
    editor.putString("shownewlevel2", shownewlevel2);
    editor.putString("shownewlevel3", shownewlevel3);
    editor.putString("shownewlevel4", shownewlevel4);
    editor.apply();
}
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    if (restoredText != null) {
        int retrieved1 = prefs.getInt("newlevel1", 0);//0 is the default value.
        int retrieved2 = prefs.getInt("newlevel2", 0);
        int retrieved3 = prefs.getInt("newlevel3", 0);
        int retrieved4 = prefs.getInt("newlevel4", 0);
        String retrievedlevel1 = prefs.getString("shownewlevel1", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
        String retrievedlevel2 = prefs.getString("shownewlevel2", "No name defined");
        String retrievedlevel3 = prefs.getString("shownewlevel3", "No name defined");
        String retrievedlevel4 = prefs.getString("shownewlevel4", "No name defined");

        displaylevel.setText(retrievedlevel1);
        displaylevel2.setText(retrievedlevel2);
        displaylevel3.setText(retrievedlevel3);
        displaylevel4.setText(retrievedlevel4);

    }

}
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putInt("newlevel1", newlevel1);
    editor.putInt("newlevel2", newlevel2);
    editor.putInt("newlevel3", newlevel3);
    editor.putInt("newlevel4", newlevel4);
    editor.putString("shownewlevel1", shownewlevel1);
    editor.putString("shownewlevel2", shownewlevel2);
    editor.putString("shownewlevel3", shownewlevel3);
    editor.putString("shownewlevel4", shownewlevel4);
    editor.apply();
  }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to store the new value and the string of that value into Shared Preferences and display them again OnResume().

Is this the correct approach or can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Look at this line... String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    if (restoredText != null) . Try to think about it a bit. You never saved "text" so on resume you check if you have "text" saved, and if yes then you go and read the rest..... Since you didn't save any "text" and the default return value is null when there is no "text" saved, basically the code in the if never executes.... Even if you copy paste together a solution, try to understand what it does.

Comment: yes i just realised that! I have removed that and I am checking if each of my retrieved strings are null, do you think that should do the trick? also on first run do you think this would crash as onResume is ran after onCreate and it may get nulls for the sharedpreferences? thanks @Alex

Comment: @Alex, quick update.. when i ran it the doses said gave the default value which is "no name defined" which is pulling from the onResume(), is there any way i can have that display the initial values first and then only the saved ones when the screen is re-entered?